# Text formatting using python

Tags: python

How to convert the following input into a tab-delimited file using Python?

Input

```
[ 49 302 515 691 909] {'prominences': array([1.495, 1.565, 1.655, 2.3, 1.88 ]), 'left_bases': array([  8, 122, 122, 122, 122]), 'right_bases': array([122, 312, 536, 764, 932]), 'widths': array([36.93773946,  7.14150718,  7.38614341, 39.32723577,  8.17883298]), 'width_heights': array([-0.4975, -0.2275, -0.0875, -0.325 ,  0.1   ]), 'left_ips': array([ 34.52777778, 298.15454545, 510.59302326, 673.91666667,904.25490196]), 'right_ips': array([ 71.46551724, 305.29605263, 517.97916667, 713.24390244,912.43373494])}
```

output

[image]

Comment: Honestly, by finding out where that input came from and making that program output something more easily parseable, such as plain JSON. That data is a mishmash of various formats and you'll have to more or less roll a bespoke parser that may or may not break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less terrible and will break with unexpected input, but happens to work with the data you have. Really, though, as said in my comment, get the program that data came from to do something saner!

**EDIT:** If your "input" is actually the output of a `print(a, b)` statement in your own program, then you can skip the horrible parsing below, and substitute those two values for `numbers` and `data`.

```
import re
import ast
import csv
import sys


def parse_horrible_data_string(s):
    numbers_string, data_string = re.match(r"^\[(.+?)\] (.+)$", s).groups()
    numbers = [int(n) for n in numbers_string.strip().split()]
    data = ast.literal_eval(data_string.replace(": array(", ": ("))
    return (numbers, data)


s = """[ 49 302 515 691 909] {'prominences': array([1.495, 1.565, 1.655, 2.3, 1.88 ]), 'left_bases': array([  8, 122, 122, 122, 122]), 'right_bases': array([122, 312, 536, 764, 932]), 'widths': array([36.93773946,  7.14150718,  7.38614341, 39.32723577,  8.17883298]), 'width_heights': array([-0.4975, -0.2275, -0.0875, -0.325 ,  0.1   ]), 'left_ips': array([ 34.52777778, 298.15454545, 510.59302326, 673.91666667,904.25490196]), 'right_ips': array([ 71.46551724, 305.29605263, 517.97916667, 713.24390244,912.43373494])}"""
numbers, data = parse_horrible_data_string(s)

data_keys = list(data.keys())
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(["No"] + data_keys)
for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    row = [number] + [data[key][i] for key in data_keys]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

outputs

```
No,prominences,left_bases,right_bases,widths,width_heights,left_ips,right_ips
49,1.495,8,122,36.93773946,-0.4975,34.52777778,71.46551724
302,1.565,122,312,7.14150718,-0.2275,298.15454545,305.29605263
515,1.655,122,536,7.38614341,-0.0875,510.59302326,517.97916667
691,2.3,122,764,39.32723577,-0.325,673.91666667,713.24390244
909,1.88,122,932,8.17883298,0.1,904.25490196,912.43373494
```

Comment: Is it possible to call the file from outside the script like using ```s = sys.argv[1]```

Comment: The absolute easiest would be to replace the `s = ...` thing with `s = sys.stdin.read()` and then pipe in your file: `python script.py < file.txt`. Note that this won't read multi-line files.

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Comment: Yes, because your input data did not match what the code expected. You could try `s = sys.stdin.read().strip()` to get rid of newlines.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: There is one small change though. What if I have "Filename: " at the begging?

Answer (score -1):

```
 import pandas as pd
 data = list()
 # data can be a dictionary
 df = pd.Dataframe(data)
 df.to_csv('filename', sep='give tab space here')
```

[please go through pandas to csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-store-in-csv)

here you can find how to convert the pandas data frame to a csv and also can specify what delimiter you want for the data.

Comment: OP has a string of data that's not in a format Pandas can just ingest.

Comment: that will help in converting the data to tab seperated values, please try my code if you have doubts

Comment: you cant write such big code for a simple thing which can be done in few steps

Comment: I got you, thought it was a normal list or json input, once the data is changed to list or dict then my process works

Comment: Yes, and that's what my "such big code" does. ;) But you don't need Pandas just to write a CSV file; the CSV module is built-in.

Comment: you can do a split at ' {' by finding the position and split it and then using json can convert to dictionary and the remaining list section can be done by map(int, str.strip().split( )), which gives us the column and then we can use pandas

Comment: Except that OP's string uses single quotes, which aren't valid JSON, and they have those `array(...)` calls which aren't valid JSON either.